# grouping two field record into one label on tree view OpenERP 7

Tags: treeview, multiple-columns, openerp-7

can openerp make one column with two header label or one column with two record field on tree view or make group column from some record fields.

this is example two field record grouping to one label on tree view.

http://s22.postimg.org/jxql4ylr5/colspan.jpg

any comment and help will much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do thar in the OpenERP framework. But if you want you can override the widget which creates the tables (I think it is not worth it)

Comment: thanks for the response ChesuCR, yes I think so. Is there someone who has a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution as follows:

XML code:

```
<group col="6" colspan="6" string="Tổng quan nhân lực toàn viện">
    <div>
        <table class="tbl_fake_header tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hr_department" rowspan="2">Phòng\khoa</th>
                    <th class="tong_so_can_bo" rowspan="2">Tổng số cán bộ</th>
                    <th colspan="4">Chức danh</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="bs">BS</th>
                    <th class="dd">ĐD</th>
                    <th class="nhs_ys_ktv">NHS,YS,KTV</th>
                    <th class="hl_ks_khac">HL,KS,Khác</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <field name="tong_quan_nhan_luc" string="Tổng quan nhân lực toàn việc">
            <tree editable="bottom" version="7.0" class="tong_quan_nhan_luc">
                <field name="hr_department"/>
                <field name="tong_so_can_bo"/>
                <field name="bs"/>
                <field name="dd"/>
                <field name="nhs_ys_ktv"/>
                <field name="hl_ks_khac"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </div>
</group>
```

CSS code:

```
/* FAKE HEADER
==================
*/
.tbl_fake_header{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}

.tbl_fake_header thead {
  border: none !important;
}
.tbl_fake_header thead  tr th{
  text-align: center !important;
  min-height: 24px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}


/*tong_quan_nhan_luc
===========================
*/
.tong_quan_nhan_luc{
  margin-top: -12px;
}
.tong_quan_nhan_luc [data-id="hr_department"],
.tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh thead tr th.hr_department{
    width: 24% !important;
}

.tong_quan_nhan_luc [data-id="tong_so_can_bo"],
.tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh thead tr th.tong_so_can_bo{
    width: 15% !important;
}

.tong_quan_nhan_luc [data-id="bs"],
.tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh thead tr th.bs{
    width: 13% !important;
}

.tong_quan_nhan_luc [data-id="dd"],
.tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh thead tr th.dd{
    width: 13% !important;
}

.tong_quan_nhan_luc [data-id="nhs_ys_ktv"],
.tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh thead tr th.nhs_ys_ktv{
    width: 18% !important;
}

.tong_quan_nhan_luc [data-id="hl_ks_khac"],
.tbl_nhan_luc_kham_chua_benh thead tr th.hl_ks_khac{
    width: 17% !important;
}

.tong_quan_nhan_luc thead{
  background: none !important;
}
.tong_quan_nhan_luc thead th{
    font-size: 0px !important;
    z-index: 0;
    border: none;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alIsT.jpg)